# why it's saying Nested block is redundant no-lone-block?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
`
import React from 'react';
import BuildControl from './BuildControl/BuildControl';
import './BuildControl.css';
const controls = [{ label: 'Cheese', type: 'cheese' }, { label: 'Bacon', type: 'bacon' }, { label: 'Meat', type: 'meat' }, { label: 'Salad', type: 'salad' }];


const BuildControls = () => {
    controls.map((ctrl) => {
        console.log("ctrl is:", ctrl.label, ctrl.type);
        return (<div className="BuildControls"><BuildControl key={ctrl.type} label={ctrl.label}></BuildControl></div>);
    });

}
export default BuildControls;
```

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T84Yy.png)
Eslint is not allowing  to return from the callback or something else is wrong.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-lone-blocks

Comment: Please include your code in text format directly in the question instead of linking to external images. You have double blocks: `const BuildControls = { { ... } }`. Remove one of them, and add a `return` keyword to return something.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks it works but why it is  forcing to remove upper { }.as it define to the scope of arrow function. this syntax works properly in other components.

Comment: There might be subtle differences from your components that work. Take another close look. Your other components might have `(` instead of `{`, e.g. `const MyComponent = () => ( ... )`. Hard to say without seeing more code.

Comment: Damn i wrote the opening & closing braces twice.

Answer (score 17):

You did not type your code correctly in your question. You left out the block that eslint is complaining about. The problem is the opening and closing brackets you have on lines by themselves is surrounding code that does not contain a function expression, or a const/let declaration which means there is no actual block being created.

```
const BuildControls = () => {
    { // Beginning of lone block
        controls.map((ctrl) => {
            console.log("ctrl is:", ctrl.label, ctrl.type);
            return (<div className="BuildControls"><BuildControl key={ctrl.type} label={ctrl.label}></BuildControl></div>);
        });

    } // End of lone block
}
export default BuildControls;
```

See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-lone-blocks

Comment: My Bad it was syntactically wrong.Thanks for answering